# Ajuda em Portugol (se e senao encadeado)

Tags: data, portugol

Foi proposto pelo professor a realização de uma atividade, que a partir de um dia, mês e ano inseridos pelo usuário, o algoritmo deve verificar se é uma data válida ou não. Considerando meses com 30 e 31 dias com exceção de fevereiro, que deve ser tratado como se sempre tivesse 29 dias. Porém, o depois de inserir as entradas, o programa me retorna as duas respostas.

```
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro dia, mes, ano

        escreva("\ndigite o dia: ")
        leia(dia)

        escreva("\ndigite o mes: ")
        leia(mes)

        escreva("\ndigite o ano: ")
        leia(ano)

        se(mes==1 e dia>0 e dia<=31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==2 e dia>0 e dia<=29 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==3 e dia>0 e dia<=31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==4 e dia>0 e dia<=30 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==5 e dia>0 e dia<=31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==6 e dia>0 e dia<=30 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==7 e dia>0 e dia<=31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==8 e dia>0 e dia<=31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==9 e dia>0 e dia<=30 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==10 e dia>0 e dia<31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==11 e dia>0 e dia<30 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==12 e dia>0 e dia<31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        senao{
            escreva("\ndata inválida!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seu `senao`se aplica apenas ao último `se`, creio que seus `se` deveriam estar todos encadeados. Utilize `ou` para todos os meses com 30 dias, idem para todos os meses com 31 dias e para fevereiro verifique se é ou não um ano bissexto.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJ4ztAYUfzc

Answer (score 1):

existe alguma estrutura no portugol que consiga encadear as condições ?
Se a sintaxe for semelhante a outras linguagens o se e senão só se relacionam no mês de dezembro.

seria algo do tipo

```
if codição
else if outra condiçao
else if outra condiçao
else data invalida
```

Ai junta tudo sabe, por exemplo se digitar mês 3, ele é diferente do mês 12, ai entra no else. No caso, deve estar funcionando apenas no mês de dezembro. Outra coisa, do mês 10 em diante a condição é <= não só <.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme outras respostas já explicaram, o `senao` só está ligado ao último `se`. Isso significa que o programa testa todos os `se`'s, e se cair em um deles, imprimirá que a data é válida, e ao chegar no último `se`, cairá no `senao` e imprimirá que a data é inválida.

Dá para simplificar todas essas verificações em menos condições. Repare que existem vários meses que possuem 30 ou 31 dias, então você pode agrupar esses casos em uma única condição. Ficaria assim:

```
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro dia, mes, ano

        escreva("\ndigite o dia: ")
        leia(dia)

        escreva("\ndigite o mes: ")
        leia(mes)

        escreva("\ndigite o ano: ")
        leia(ano)

        se (mes <= 0 ou mes > 12 ou ano <= 0) {
            escreva("\nData inválida!")
        } senao {
            inteiro ultimoDia
            se (mes == 2) {
                ultimoDia = 29
            } senao se (mes == 1 ou mes == 3 ou mes == 5 ou mes == 7 ou mes == 8 ou mes == 10 ou mes == 12) {
                ultimoDia = 31
            } senao {
                ultimoDia = 30
            }
            se (dia <= 0 ou dia > ultimoDia) {
                escreva("\nData inválida!")
            } senao {
                escreva("\nData válida!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Primeiro eu verifico se o mês e ano são válidos. Se não for, nem adianta verificar o dia, então eu já posso mostrar a mensagem e parar.

Se o mês e ano forem válidos, eu verifico qual o último dia do mês, e verifico se o dia ultrapassa este valor. O enunciado diz para considerar fevereiro sempre com 29 dias, mas se tivesse que verificar ano bissexto, bastaria colocar outro `se` dentro do `se (mes == 2)`.

Fica bem mais simples assim do que fazer um `se` para cada mês.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu me lembro do Portugol a sintaxe da estrutura `se` é diferente:

```
se(condição)entao
    Bloco de Comando
fimse
```

Exemplo [aqui](https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1044754-resolvido-algoritmo-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-se-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-caso-visualg/).

E para essa função acredito que usar a estrutura ["escolha caso"](https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/estrutura-de-selecao-multipla-escolha-caso/) é uma opção melhor.

Comment: Ivan, esse é o Portugol Studio, ele agora tem chaves, suporte a bibliotecas etc... Ficou diferente mesmo, tem uma versão online: https://portugol-webstudio.cubos.io/ide

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso o comando "senao" está sendo aplicado apenas ao último "se". Veja o mesmo código organizado de outra forma, apenas para facilitar o entendimento

```
...

        se(mes==11 e dia>0 e dia<30 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        }

        se(mes==12 e dia>0 e dia<31 e ano>0){
            escreva("\nData válida!")
        } senao {
            escreva("\nData inválida!")
        }
    }
}
```

Uma solução é encadear os comandos, colocando um "senao" entre cada um dos blocos de "se". Por exemplo:

```
    ...
    se(mes==1 e dia>0 e dia<=31 e ano>0){
        escreva("\nData válida!")
    } senao se(mes==2 e dia>0 e dia<=29 e ano>0){
        escreva("\nData válida!")
    } senao se(mes==3 e dia>0 e dia<=31 e ano>0){
        escreva("\nData válida!")
    } senao se(mes==4 e dia>0 e dia<=30 e ano>0){
        escreva("\nData válida!")
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alguém pode me ajudar, quando faço esse algoritimo ele sempre da senha incorreta mesmo eu tentando colocar a senha certa, o que eu erro? e queria retornar caso desse senha incorreta queria voltar para pessoa tentar colocar a senha +1 vez

programa

{

```
funcao inicio()
{
 real valor_saque, saldo
 inteiro senha_saque, num_agencia, num_conta, senha
     
 
 valor_saque = 0
 senha_saque = 0
 num_conta = 0
 num_agencia = 0
 senha = 0
 

 escreva ("Seja BEM-VINDO\n")
 escreva ("Informe o número da sua agência:")
 leia (num_agencia)
 escreva ("Informe o numero da sua conta:")
  leia (num_conta)
  escreva ("Informe sua senha: 1")
  leia (senha)

  se (senha==1234){   
  
  escreva ("Login com sucesso")
  escreva ("\nQual valor deseja sacar? ")
  leia (valor_saque)
  escreva ("Saque realiado com sucesso!")}
  senao  
  {
  escreva ("Senha Incorreta!")}
```