# Erro de expressão "se"

Tags: if, sintaxe, portugol

Meu código está dando esse erro na primeira expressão `se`:

> "A expressão não foi iniciada corretamente. Insira o caracter '(' para corrigir o problema"

```
real m1, m2, m3
    escreva("\n Digite o peso da primeira moeda= ")
    leia (m1)
    escreva("\n Digite o peso da segunda moeda= ")
    leia (m2)
    escreva("\n Digite o peso da terceira moeda= ")
    leia (m3)
    se (m1< m2, m3) escreva ("\nA primeira moeda é mais leve")
    se (m2< m1, m3) escreva ("\nA segunda moeda é mais leve")
    senao escreva ("\nA terceira moeda é mais leve")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe essa sintaxe que usou para fazer comparação. Leia a [documentação](http://orion.ipt.pt/%7Emanso/Portugol/help/operadores_logicos.html) da linguagem para usar qualquer recurso. A sintaxe correta (sem me preocupar se a lógica está correta, porque nem temos certeza sobre o objetivo) seria:

```
se (m1 < m2 e m1 < m3)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/And.ptg).

O mesmo vale para o outro condicional.

Você está fazendo duas comparações completamente diferentes que definem se algo é menor e o resultado dessas comparações são concatenadas através do operador `e` que dá verdadeiro se, e somente se, as duas expressões da esquerda e da direta dele são verdadeiras.

A sintaxe do `se` parece errada também. A Não ser que esteja sando um dialeto diferente. Veja a [documentação](http://orion.ipt.pt/%7Emanso/Portugol/help/se.html). Está faltando um `entao`. E talvez falte um `senao se` para dar a lógica correta. Se estiver um dialeto que usa chaves, então pode ver a pergunta [Ajuda em Portugol (se e senao encadeado)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/447246/101) que tem um exemplo de como funciona.